# How to remove a record from a table valued parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I would like to know how to remove a value from a Table Valued Parameter in SQL?
Is this even possible? If not, what would be the workaround?

Please see my code below and note the comments. The comments portion is where I would like to insert a line that would allow me to remove a record from the TVP @Record_NumList

Once that record is removed, I then proceed to insert a new one (basically, I don't want to execute the stored procedure on an existing record).

```
DECLARE @RecordID int
DECLARE @RecordID_NumList as Le_NumberList
DECLARE cur_DelRec CURSOR
      FOR
            SELECT DBRecordID from <<table_name>>

      OPEN cur_DelRec

            FETCH NEXT from cur_DelRec into @RecordID
            INSERT into @RecordID_NumList(@RecordID)
            WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                  BEGIN
                        exec <<stored_procedure>> @RecordID_NumList

                        /* I'm stuck here:  */
                /* Need to remove from the existing record
                from @RecordID_NumList */

                        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_DelRec into @RecordID
                        INSERT into @RecordID_NumList(@RecordID)
                  END

      CLOSE cur_DelRec
DEALLOCATE cur_DelRec
```

On a more general level, is a TVP a collection? Let's say I chose not to delete it from @Record_NumList. What would happen in that case?

I apologize, but I'm still learning SQL and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ray

Comment: `DELETE FROM @RecordID_NumList`?

Comment: For the love of god do not use cursors and loops! In all seriousness, if you can re-write this to be declarative, it will perform much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table valued parameters works just like a regular table. You should be able to just do something like this:

```
delete from @Record_numList where [field] = [value]
```

Comment: I did some testing and, yes, that's exactly how it works. Thank you!